# Error code 1064 raises, maybe syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table approval
(
    app_id smallint not null,
    visitor_id smallint(5),
    approve varchar(5),

    primary key (app_id) auto increment
    foreign key (visitor_id) references trans_req_visitor(visitor_id)
    constraint approval check (approval in ('TRUE', 'FALSE'))
);
```

I don't find where it causes an error, where am I making mistake?

Comment: Post the exact error message. Don't make us guess.

Comment: Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'auto increment
FOREIGN KEY (visitor_id) REFERENCES trans_req_visitor(visitor_id)' at line 5
Line 1, column 1

Execution finished after 0 s, 1 error(s) occurred.

Comment: please dont vote down bro, i already have less reputations

Comment: Please follow [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) bro. Also, instead of commenting, you should [edit the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22653607/edit) to include information that would be helpful in solving your problem.

Comment: create table approval(app_id smallint not null auto_increment,visitor_id mallint(5),approve varchar(5),primary key (app_id),FOREIGN KEY (visitor_id) EFERENCES trans_req_visitor(visitor_id),constraint approval check (approval in 'TRUE', 'FALSE')));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table approval(app_id smallint not null auto_increment,visitor_id mallint(5),approve varchar(5),primary key (app_id),FOREIGN KEY (visitor_id) EFERENCES trans_req_visitor(visitor_id),constraint approval check (approval in 'TRUE', 'FALSE')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after

```
primary key (app_id) auto increment
```

Change your query to

```
create table approval(
app_id smallint not null,
visitor_id smallint(5),
approve varchar(5),
primary key (app_id) auto_increment,
FOREIGN KEY (visitor_id) REFERENCES trans_req_visitor(visitor_id),
constraint approval check (approval in ('TRUE', 'FALSE'))
);
```

Comment: still not working guys, it gives the same error still

Answer (score 1):

missing comma near `auto increment` and `REFERENCES trans_req_visitor(visitor_id)`

Try this

```
create table approval(
app_id smallint not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
visitor_id smallint(5),
approve varchar(5),
primary key (app_id),
FOREIGN KEY (visitor_id) REFERENCES trans_req_visitor(visitor_id),
constraint approval check (approval in ('TRUE', 'FALSE'))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
create table approval(
app_id smallint not null auto_increment,
visitor_id smallint(5),
approve varchar(5),
primary key (app_id),
FOREIGN KEY (visitor_id) REFERENCES trans_req_visitor(visitor_id),
constraint approval check (approval in ('TRUE', 'FALSE'))
);
```

(missed commas, mistyped and misplaced `auto_increment`)

*Note* `check` is not supported in MySQL. This syntax is allowed **only** for compatibility reasons.